# How can I debug a smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, testing

When developing my smart contract, how can I debug it? Are there any debugging, testing tools or simulators that I can use to examine my code?

Comment: [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org) has stack traces and console.log

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. The [Remix IDE](http://remix.ethereum.org/) has a great integrated block-by-block simulator and debugger.
2. [Ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache) allows fast contract testing without the hassle of running a node.
3. Once the contract is live, the [etherscan.io](http://etherscan.io) block explorer can be used to view internal state and EVM execution logs.

Comment: Mix IDE has been discontinued...

Comment: @CodingYourLife updated the answer with the latest resources

Answer (score 18):

Those are all good tools, but I have found the logging events is much easier method for debugging, plus if you are doing anything with money you want to keep a record of what happened.

In Solidity, you log with [Events](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contracts.html#events).  You can then listen to all events on your contract with [web3.js "allEvents" callback](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-allevents)

This is how I debug my (currently) 780 lines of solidity.

Comment: Could you  please elaborate a bit more on how you go about debugging with events?  Using a javascript console in order to connect with the contract manually and watch for events or are you using a script somehow to automate the process? This sounds like a good technique and I am trying to apply it by console.log event results in truffle unit tests but have not managed to make it work yet!

Comment: I'm using nodejs scripts, which work with web3.js just fine.  Here's a hacked up version of ether pudding that includes logging (but from one contract only for now), see unit tests for how it works.   https://github.com/barkthins/ether-pudding

Comment: But when execution throws no events are logged in Solidity

Comment: good point.  I try to avoid exceptions if at all possible because they eat up all your gas, amongst other things.   I would love it if someone added an answer on how to post-hoc debug an exception being thrown.  AFAICT you have to examine a node's logs.  I hope someone is working on a 'soft' exception feature in the VM, the 'hard exception' is basically the equivalent of a BSOD...

Comment: @PaulS And if no events are written even in the simplest case like dumping variables without prior condition, how can I know what is wrong? (and in a case were no exception is logged)

Comment: @PaulS When you face an error in some functions with 100 lines of code, no events will be occured.

Answer (score 12):

to debug a contract you could use the [solidity browser](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/)

the debugger provides you the ability to debug any transaction (creation or call) step by step  and to visualize the memory/storage space. it helps you to trace the gas cost by opcode and the remaining gas after each step.

> To debug transactions, there's two way of doing that:
>
> 1-using a block number and a transaction index.
>   [image]
>
> 2-using a transaction hash.

[image]

When loading the transaction succeed, the hash, from and to  field will show up. Then the vm trace is loaded.
[image]

> The debugger itself contains several controls that allow stepping over
>   the trace and seing the current state of a selected step.
>
> **Slider and Stepping action:**
>
> The slider allows to move quickly from a state to another. Stepping
>   actions are:
>
> **Step Into Back Step Over Back Step Over Forward Step Into Forward Jump**
>   **Next Call** (this will select the next state that refers to a context
>   changes - CALL, CALLCODE, DELEGATECALL, CREATE) State Viewer:
>
> The upper right panel contains basic informations about the current
>   step:
>
> **VMTraceStep**: the index in the trace of the current step. Step Add
>   memory Gas: gas used by this step Remaining gas: gas left Loaded
>   address: the current code loaded, refers to the executing code. The
>   other 6 panels describe the current selected state:
>
> **Instructions list**: list of all the instruction that defines the
>   current executing code. Stack Storage Changes Memory Call Data$ Call
>   Stack

**breakpoints** 
in remix Breakpoints can be added and removed by clicking the left margin of the first line of code. You can add as many breakpoints as you want. 
[image]

Comment: Weh I try to debug a transaction, copying transaction hash and clicking the `start debugging` button does nothing except writing `0xc09ff6fb32dd6ef66f5691367c11c762c8f730aadeab065d57f8137cd3746bfc is not a contract invokation or contract creation` in the log.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `truffle debug` command: http://truffleframework.com/blog/announcing-full-portable-solidity-debugger

It supports:

- Code stepping (over, into, out, next, instruction, etc.)
- Current code location, including the address of the running contract
- Breakpoints
- Watch expressions
- Variable inspection (stack, memory and storage)
- Custom expression evaluation using Solidity variables

Answer (score 1):

For debugging Truffle Javascript tests in Visual Studio Code, this answer worked for me: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/41096/3708

Answer (score 1):

latest version truffle has an inbuilt debugger that can be used to debug state  of a failed transaction.

```
$ truffle debug <transaction-id>
```

where `<transaction-id>` is id of the errored transaction,

once debugger is launched follow the instruction to walkthrough and print variable state etc

find out more here :
https://www.trufflesuite.com/blog/announcing-full-portable-solidity-debugger

Answer (score 1):

I recently released a public beta of my Solidity Debugger, which is a Visual Studio Code extension. It integrates with the Hardhat framework and allows you to step through solidity smart contracts. Check it out here: https://soliditydebugger.org/