# Writing secure Smart Contracts in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, contract-design

With the **DAO hack**, it becomes even more important for developers to write secure `smart contracts` and be aware of pitfalls.

> Are there any good reference points/links which can describe the best practices around security of Solidity based Smart Contracts?

Comment: [List questions are generally off-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98334/226837) and [here is some more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11780/22683).  This has been converted to: Community wiki questions don't accrue rep and have a lower full editing reputation threshold. Questions should be manually converted to community wiki when they are marginal fits or 'list of X' questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion. This affects the question and all answers.

Answer (score 9):

This answer is a wiki that's editable by the community (add and explain as needed.)

[Thinking About Smart Contract Security - Vitalik Buterin 2016-06-19](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/19/thinking-smart-contract-security/)

https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/10/smart-contract-security

http://hackingdistributed.com/2016/06/16/scanning-live-ethereum-contracts-for-bugs

https://github.com/LeastAuthority/ethereum-analyses/blob/master/GasEcon.md

http://martin.swende.se/blog/Devcon1-and-contract-security.html

http://www.kingoftheether.com/postmortem.html

[How can I debug a smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/184/how-can-i-debug-a-smart-contract/1434#1434)

http://www.blunderingcode.com/writing-secure-solidity/

https://github.com/ConsenSys/smart-contract-best-practices