# Ethereum Contract auditing(solidity)

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, security

I am a student of Information Security and my teacher has given me the task to know about the details of auditing that is being done on Ethereum smart contracts that are written using solidity. Details like what are the parameters that are checked, how is auditing carried out, and what is the role of inline assembly in performing this task. I've searched a lot on internet but did not find anything useful. Can anyone of you please guide me or provide me the track which I can follow to achieve this task?

Comment: There is no fixed set of rules. It should be much like any other security code audit. To get started you should read some of the existing audits ENS audit: https://gist.github.com/pipermerriam/6bec14a2d8d8abb904529849c6b03131, TokenCard audit https://github.com/MonolithDAO/token/blob/master/audit/TokenSaleAudit.pdf, Bancor audit https://gist.github.com/holiman/a5e8690cd1dcc875b9f4f39297d587be.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no 'standard' way of automatically auditing a solidity contract; of course you have the compiler, that checks for syntax errors and overflows etc. For the details how to use it, please check out [this documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/using-the-compiler.html).

For a general security auditing of any contract, sanity checks will be performed, just like on normal coding. White hat hackers and auditors will look for any weaknesses in a contract, for example, missing modifiers (like 'internal', the famous parity hack, where 30 million was stolen because of missing this keyword), but also if calls that should only be called by the owner have the code to back that up, that sort of thing. 
This article on medium is pretty nice and covers some of the basic things to look out [here](https://medium.com/@merunasgrincalaitis/how-to-audit-a-smart-contract-most-dangerous-attacks-in-solidity-ae402a7e7868)

Good luck with your school assignment!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a methodological approach (checklist) to audit smart contracts with a fixed set of rules:

http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8551/methodological-security-review-of-a-smart-contract