# ethereum smart contract security check

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, contract-design, contract-invocation

How to prevent smart contract from the vulnerabilities? what are all the security measurements we need to consider before publishing our smart contract?

Regards
Mani

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Methodological security review of a smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8551/methodological-security-review-of-a-smart-contract)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vulnerabilities prevention is what you do while coding the contract, i.e. following good practices, like what you can find at
https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/

and then, when the coding is done and everything is tested, hiring independent auditors ( not the same people who coded the contract ), those you have to find. There are plenty of companies doing it - check https://solidified.io/ and, naturally, Google search.

Answer (score 1):

Exist some websites with useful information, and of course use correct tools for development.

https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/

In the link above you can check best practices and tools and known attacks.