# Are Ethereum transactions atomic

Tags: contract-development, evm

I apologize in advance if my question is dumb.

I want to make a smart contract which will handle money from the outside. However, I haven't been able to find any information about multithreading on the Ethereum network.

Does it work as a multithreaded environment, or are all transactions in a block executed in a linear fashion? I'm asking since I don't know is there need for the introduction of custom-made atomic variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not concerned if EVM implementation itself is multithreaded or not (there are several implementations, you do not care.)

> Does it work as a multithreaded environment, or are all transactions in a block executed in a linear fashion

Yes. All transactions are atomic by the definition. The whole block gets executed, or none of a block gets executed. You do not need to worry about atomicity as a developer. However, you still need to worry [about re-entrancy](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8551/security-review-checklist-for-a-smart-contract).

If a transaction cannot get into a block, miners will try to fit into another block.

[More information about the transaction lifecycle here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65830983/how-sending-transactions-and-receiving-events-work-in-backends-in-ethereum-block/65842575#65842575).

Comment: Yes I have read up a lot about re-entrancy, but this specific question came to my mind because I didn't know whether I should worry about data consistency, locks, mutexes etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for multithreading, look at Solana. EVM is single-threaded. https://fullstacks.org/materials/ethereumbook/14_evm.html