# Does only function involving ETH transactions need reentrancy guard?

Tags: solidity, synthetix

I thought so as it may induces fallback() functions, however, I saw in Synthetix's staking contracts, they use reentrancy guard on so many functions that does not involve ETH at all?

https://github.com/Synthetixio/synthetix/blob/develop/contracts/StakingRewards.sol

Comment: please clarify which function because i don't see any abnormal.

Comment: no it has nothing to do with "only involving Eth transactions"

Comment: Also see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8551/ethereum-smart-contract-security-checklist/8593#8593

Answer (score 0):

Any contract that makes external function calls should at least be *considered* for reentrancy protection, because the external contract could be abused in a malicious way.

For example, if you are working with ERC777 tokens, you have to pay careful attention to your code to protect against reentrancy through the `tokensReceived()` hook. [This was the cause of the $11.7M Agave/Hundred Finance hack.](https://rekt.news/agave-hundred-rekt/)