# How do I write smart contracts that are LP tokens?

Tags: solidity, tokens, liquidity-provider

I'm very new to blockchain and DeFi, and I'd like to ask a questions regarding LP tokens.

If I wanted to list 4 LP tokens, with farm reward proportions of: 80/60/40/20, how do I go about writing them? (Ideally, I would like to generate them from factory contracts)

Comment: The context is to build a test app for farming LPs

Answer (score 0):

Each DEX will have their own LP token contract. You do not build them.

For token rewards / liquidity mining [you can clone MasterCher from SushiSwap](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-farm/blob/master/contracts/MasterChef.sol).

Naturally, please know what you are doing and [don't do stupid security bugs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8593/620).