# When should I use ReentrancyGuard in a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, security, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, reentrant-attacks

I am looking at the [`ReentrancyGuard`](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/security#ReentrancyGuard) smart contract from Open Zeppelin and I don't understand when I have to use it.

Is it necessary in all my smart contracts or do I only have to add it in some particular cases? If the latter is true, what are those cases?

Comment: It's complicated, see the [discussion](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1602999187863371778) I started about this on Twitter.

Comment: [Please see the security checklist for smart contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8551/ethereum-smart-contract-security-checklist/8593#8593)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nonReentrant modifier is used on a per function basis and prevents more than one protected function being called at a time.

The most common case is when your function at some point performs an external call or transfer which allows a threat actor to then re-enter your function again without completing it. This is when you would want a nonReentrant modifier.

It is not always required, but definitely something to consider adding to your functions.

Comment: Can it cause any harm when added and not needed?

Comment: It can break your contract's functionality if a protected function tries to call another protected function as that is not allowed, however this can be fixed with a workaround with internal/external functions. It comes down to your design. Also there is the small gas costs to consider as well