# How to debug Bad jump destination error

Tags: contract-development

I am trying to work through the https://ethereum.org/token#improved-coin tutorial. I deployed the contract to testnet. Initialized tokens, set the buy and sell price. Now, one of my accounts has 50 tokens. I am trying to sell some tokens by calling

> >contractInstance.sell(10)
>   '0x936906cddd13155cf3a5be090363aa4b1a6f909ebd556e80cbb8e01234c52e80'

This results in a [Bad jump destination] error. You can see the transaction here: https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x936906cddd13155cf3a5be090363aa4b1a6f909ebd556e80cbb8e01234c52e80

Here is the entire source code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e40d6a7433431776c7c0ff330eaee126

How do I debug this issue?

Comment: https://testnet.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x936906cddd13155cf3a5be090363aa4b1a6f909ebd556e80cbb8e01234c52e80

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand that trace. Where can I learn to understand this? Thanks.

Comment: read http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/184/how-can-i-debug-a-smart-contract/1434#1434